# I am getting Null check operator used on a null value error in Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When I am adding bottom navifation in app then I am getting this issue:

```
List<Widget> pages = <Widget>[
    LandingPage(),
    ProfilePage()
  ];
```

For more information please check the below image, Please help me in this.
[image: Issue Image]

Comment: would be great if you can show the code where the stack trace is pointing at `home_controller.dart`

Answer (score 0):

That error gets thrown when the value given is null (so it can't be used) and you don't provide a fallback for when this happens.

To avoid using a null value use the operator `??`.
Example if you have a function that may return a null value:

```
Int? maybeNullInt = getInt() ?? 20;
```